# timestamp difference (which is in string) in hive

Tags: hive, timestamp

How to do difference of timestamp (which is in `string`) in hive?

I tried using

```
date_format(column_name,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss')
```

to convert into a `timestamp` but the difference is giving me a `null` value

Comment: please post how the timestamp string looks like and also the expected output.

Comment: (step_start_time         string,
step_end_time         string)

step_start_time formart - 2018-03-01 00:08:48.409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with unix_timestamp function

```
select unix_timestamp('2018-03-03 00:08:48.409') - unix_timestamp('2018-03-02 00:08:48.409');
+--------+--+
|  _c0   |
+--------+--+
| 86400  |
+--------+--+
```

Your query would be something like

```
select (unix_timestamp(step_start_time) - unix_timestamp(step_end_time ))diff;
```

Comment: this works thanks,  earlier I was doing from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(unix_timestamp(step_start_time) - unix_timestamp(step_end_time )) which is messing the output ...now I got the issue